# Display Please Wait message while long Python function in process

Tags: python, time, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a code that analyzes the metadata of a Video file and displays it in LCD QT widgets

this prosses takes almost 15 to 20 seconds and I would like to display (please waite) or show a progress bar.

I add a progress bar but it's independent of the function(nothing to do with it).

here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import timeit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor,QFont
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import subprocess
import shlex
import json
import sys
import webbrowser
import threading

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(470, 525)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 470, 143, 25))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setTextVisible(True)
        self.lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 50, 146, 50))
        self.lcd1 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 100, 146, 50))
        self.lcd2= QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 150, 146, 50))
        self.lcd3 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 146, 50))
        self.lcd4 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 250, 146, 50))
        self.lcd5 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 300, 146, 50))
        self.lcd6 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcd6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 350, 146, 50))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 430, 121, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.dep3)
        self.txtt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtt.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        self.txtt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 0, 300, 400))

        self.txtt.setText("Video"
                             "\nCode Name .................."
                             "\n\nHorizont........................"
                             "\n\nVertical.........................."
                             "\n\nDisplay Aspect Ratio......"
                             "\n\nRefrence........................."
                             "\n\nB frames........................."
                             "\n\nStart Bits......................."
                             "\n\nSample Aspect ratio......."
                             "\n\nBit Rate.........................")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ratio"))
     ###########  This is the Function that i want to calculate its time

    def task1(self):
         cmd = "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams"
         args = shlex.split(cmd)

         myurl="HERE YOU CAN PUT THE VIDEO STREAM OR ITS DIRECTOY"
         args.append(myurl)

         ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
         ffprobeOutput = json.loads(ffprobeOutput)

         codec_name = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['codec_name']
         width = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['width']
         height = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['height']
         display_aspect_ratio = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['display_aspect_ratio']

         sample_aspect_ratio = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['sample_aspect_ratio']
         refs = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['refs']
         has_b_frames = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['has_b_frames']
         # start_pts = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['start_pts']
         # bit_rate= ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['bit_rate']
         self.lcd.display(has_b_frames)
         self.lcd1.display(codec_name)
         self.lcd2.display(width)
         self.lcd3.display(height)
         self.lcd4.display(display_aspect_ratio)
         self.lcd5.display(sample_aspect_ratio)
         self.lcd6.display(refs)
         # self.lcd8.display(start_pts)
         # self.lcd9.display(bit_rate)
         self.lcd.show()
         self.lcd1.show()
         self.lcd2.show()
         self.lcd3.show()
         self.lcd4.show()
         self.lcd5.show()
         self.lcd6.show()
         print("done!!")

    def task2(self):
        self.completed = 0
        while self.completed < 100:
            self.completed += 0.00002
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.completed)

    def dep1(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.task1)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.task2)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()

    def dep3(self):
        d1 = threading.Thread(target=self.dep1)
        d1.start()
        d1.join()
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't update widgets from different threads. Use signals and slots instead to communicate data. Here is an example using a `QThread` and a custom worker class. The worker class does the actual work. When the analysis is done, it emits a signal with the result.

```
# Worker class that fetches data and emits result when ready.
class Analyzer(QtCore.QObject):
    result_ready = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def do_work(self):
        cmd = "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams"
        args = shlex.split(cmd)

        myurl = "HERE YOU CAN PUT THE VIDEO STREAM OR ITS DIRECTOY"
        args.append(myurl)

        ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
        ffprobeOutput = json.loads(ffprobeOutput)

        result = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]

        self.result_ready.emit(result)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    ....

    def dep3(self):
        # set progress bar to undetermined state and disable button
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)

        # create thread for doing heavy work
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = Analyzer()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.do_work)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.worker.result_ready.connect(self.process_result)
        self.thread.start()

    def process_result(self, result):
        codec_name = result['codec_name']
        width = result['width']
        height = result['height']
        display_aspect_ratio = result['display_aspect_ratio']

        sample_aspect_ratio = result['sample_aspect_ratio']
        refs = result['refs']
        has_b_frames = result['has_b_frames']
        # start_pts = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['start_pts']
        # bit_rate= ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['bit_rate']
        self.lcd.display(has_b_frames)
        self.lcd1.display(codec_name)
        self.lcd2.display(width)
        self.lcd3.display(height)
        self.lcd4.display(display_aspect_ratio)
        self.lcd5.display(sample_aspect_ratio)
        self.lcd6.display(refs)

        # reset progress bar and push button
        self.progressBar.setRange(0,100)
        self.progressBar.setValue(100)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        print("done!!")
```

Comment: Danke sehr Heike ,,you are genius :)